# Cannot find module './img.jpg' after build in nuxtjs works on dev mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Works fine on dev mode, after build get this below **error** when upload a new image then try to render image:

> Error: Cannot find module './2019-10-16T21:50:32.958Zhotel-img.jpg'

[image]

Here is the **method**:

```
docImage(index) {
  let imgPath = this.userDocs[index].document.documentPath;
  imgPath = imgPath.substring(imgPath.indexOf("/") + 1);
  return require(`../../uploads/${imgPath}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> when upload a new image then try to render image:

Thats a reason. When you require images they are bundled by webpack at build time. So any image that isnt available at build time wont be available.

Comment: Yeah!!! Got the reason. But how to get this thing work on production, without requiring it's not working on dev mode also.

Comment: The only way is to upload it where you can access them by url without require. e.g img src='/staticpath/img.jpg'